# how do I remove the curtain opening effect with uiimagepickercontroller

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

when I do

```
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];
```

there would be always a "8 pieces of blade opening and then the preview shows" kind of effect. 
my questions is how do i skip the balde opening part and jump right to the preview? is there a way to do that?

also can i hold/resume preview programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to "build your own" using Apple's [AV Foundation framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html).

It is entirely possible, but likely a lot more work than you want to do :) if you're just taking a picture.  For an advanced photo/movie app, though, it's more flexible than `UIImagePickerController`.